# How can I get sfRouting to shut up in a task?

Tags: logging, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have a symfony task, with a context instance creation :

```
sfContext::createInstance($this->configuration);
```

The context is needed because of a call to the `get_component` helper function (in order to generate the body of an email). I know [sfContext::getInstance() is bad](http://webmozarts.com/2009/07/01/why-sfcontextgetinstance-is-bad/), but I did not write it and can't remove it.

My problem is this line triggers the logging of routing - related messages:

```
  >> sfPatternRouting Match route "homepage" (/) for / with parameters array (  'module' => 'default',  'action' => 'index',)
```

How can I get sfRouting to shut up? I keep getting email from my crontab repeating this useless piece of information.

How would I change the configuration so that the options passed to the routing constructor do not contain `"logging" => "true"` ?

I would like the routing to shut up no matter what my factories.yml files contain.

Of course, it there is an error, be it logged to STDOUT or STDERR, I still want to get an email.

Vlad asked me for my code, so I created a tiny project so you can easily reproduce the bug.
Here it is: https://github.com/greg0ire/pwet

If you want to easily reproduce the bug, I created a brand new dummy project, which you can clone.
Here are the steps to reproduce the bug:

```
git clone git://github.com/greg0ire/pwet.git
cd pwet
git submodule init
git submodule update
php web/frontend_dev.php
./symfony pwet --application="frontend"
```

Notice how `php web/frontend_dev.php` is important. It does not generate the same cache files as the CLI would

Comment: I never try to find a solution about that but I'll wait for an answer too! :)

Comment: Are you in dev mode? `new sfCommandOption('env', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The environment', 'dev/stage/prod')`?

Comment: `var_dump($this->configuration->getEnvironment())` displays "dev"

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish this by creating a new environment called "task" and configuring the "routing" class to a new class I made called "DummyRouting".

apps/frontend/config/factories.yml:

```
task:
  routing:
     class: DummyRouting
```

DummyRouting.class.php

```
class DummyRouting extends sfPatternRouting
{
  public function connect($name, $route)
  {
  }

  public function parse($url)
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

and of course make sure to specify the "task" environment as your default for convenience.

YourTask.class.php in configure()

```
...
new sfCommandOption('env', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The environment', 'task'),
...
```

Comment: looks good! I won't be able to test this right now, tomorrow maybe... I'm still getting a lot of cron emails that will remind me to try your solution anyway. For the moment, you get a +1 for your good idea.

Answer (score 0):

That only happens when you have debugging on (dev environment by default)

The default value for the environment is defined in the configure method of the task (something like the line in my prev message). You can override it by using the argument `--env=dev/prod/stage/etc` in command line, when executing the task. You probably want to switch to production environment (prod) so you won't see the route related messages (or other debugging messages for that matter). This is an example from one of my tasks:

```
protected function configure()
{
    $this->addOptions(array(
      new sfCommandOption('application', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The application name', 'frontend'),
      new sfCommandOption('env', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The environment', 'prod'), 
      new sfCommandOption('connection', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The connection name', 'propel'),
    ));

   // other stuff here      
}
```

Comment: Here is the title of the emails I'm getting : `/usr/bin/php /some/path/symfony some-namespace:some-task --env=prod` . I guess you must be wrong somewhere...

Comment: That's only if you want to specify an environment. Otherwise the one from the `configure` method is considered. So look at this line `      new sfCommandOption('env', null, sfCommandOption::PARAMETER_REQUIRED, 'The environment', 'dev')` and check if you have "dev" or "prod". In dev mode you'll see debug messages like the ones you said.

Comment: What I mean is that the cron which is spamming me with these messages is using the 'prod' environement. And still displays these messages.

Comment: You said, that `var_dump($this->configuration->getEnvironment())` displays 'dev'. That means that somewhere somebody/something, somehow is changing your environment. Is it possible to view the task code?

Comment: This was on my local machine. In the production environment, I guess it displays 'prod'. Both environments have the same problem.

Comment: I did even better, check my question please.

Comment: I just cloned your project and ran the task with `./symfony pwet --application="frontend" --env=prod` and didn't get any debug messages....

Comment: did you generate the cache for prod first? `php web/index.php`

Comment: Yes, i did. Working like it should.

Comment: Indeed. Maybe be because of the NoLogger in factories.yml . I'll try to change some things

Comment: Something must be changing your environment. Only in debug mode are those messages displayed.

Answer (score -1):

The only way can set `logging` to `false` is by doing it manually in your `factories.yml`:

```
prod:
  routing:
    param:
      logging: false
```

Using this solution my tasks are now quiet !

Comment: "I would like the routing to shut up no matter what my factories.yml files contain." including (`logging: true`)